# Dataframe to textfile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am struggling to find the correct arguments to use np.savetxt() for my dataframe. I don't want to use df.to_csv(), I explicitly need a txt-file. My dataframe is the following:

```
df
        TotalMP  ZoneA  ZoneB  ...  Zone11  Zone12           Date_and_time
2          36.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-10 18:00:01.200
3           0.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-10 18:00:01.400
4           0.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-10 18:00:01.600
5           0.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-10 18:00:01.800
6          47.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-10 18:00:02.000
        ...    ...    ...  ...     ...     ...                     ...
143993     40.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-11 01:59:59.400
143994     40.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-11 01:59:59.600
143995     41.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-11 01:59:59.800
143996     54.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-11 02:00:00.000
143997     97.0    0.0    0.0  ...     0.0     0.0 2021-01-11 02:00:00.200

[143981 rows x 18 columns]
```

I'm trying the following:

```
np.savetxt('hourly_median_cage1.txt', df, fmt='%f', delimiter=";")
```

But I think it doesn't recognize the Date_and_time datetime format. How can I fix this? I'd also would index the dataframe on Date_and_time before saving it to a textfile.

Thank you

Comment: `df.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
np.savetxt(r'c:\data\np.txt', df, fmt='%f',delimiter=";")
```

Alternatively you can save it to a .csv and from there convert it into a .txt (although this is not the cleanest solution for sure)

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
df = df.set_index('Date_and_time')
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```